# MySQL bug with rounding decimal values

Tags: mysql, rounding

I wonder why MySQL produce different result when rounding decimal points for 2 different rows as shown in my screenshot here.

[image]

The first `183.25 * 9.7` row is rounded incorrectly which should be round to `1777.53` where as the 2nd row `186.55 * 9.7` is rounding correctly to `1809.54`.

I wonder why is different result of rounding for different rows in a same database?

Comment: Mysql is probably using floating point arithmetic  resulting in the first expression likely to be less than .525

Answer (score 2):

For your `ROUND()` column, MySQL is doing what you asked and giving you 3 decimal places (the second argument of `ROUND()` is 3).

However, your total_amount column is **NOT** rounded. The rounding that you see is being done by whatever GUI tool you are using to display the results, and it does not seem to use [MySQL half-up rounding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html).

To clarify, lets take a look at your query, which has 5 columns:

```
SELECT 
  p.quantity, 
  p.weight, 
  p.unit_price, 
  ROUND(p.quantity * p.weight * p.unit_price, 3), 
  (p.quantity * p.weight * p.unit_price) as total_amount 
FROM ...
```

As you can see, column 5 (which you aliased as `total_amount`) is just an arithmetic operation, there is no `ROUND()` around it. The rounding you see on your grid (1809.54) is being performed by your admin tool, not MySQL.

You can verify the actual behavior on the MySQL CLI:

```
MySQL [test]> SELECT (183.25 * 9.70);
+-----------------+
| (183.25 * 9.70) |
+-----------------+
|       1777.5250 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.018 sec)
```

Comment: The `total_amount` column is rounded as you can see in my 2nd highlighted row.

Comment: @IainH. in your `SELECT` statement, look carefully at the syntax left of `total_amount`. The multiplication is between parenthesis, but there is no `ROUND` operation happening, you are just multiplying the values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found out the issue was caused by my `weight` column was defined as `double(18,2)` which sometimes it has this incorrect rounding behavior. I convert it to `decimal(18,2)` and ran the same query again and I get correct result after that.